# How to merge multiple json object into one json array in shell

Tags: linux, json, jq

I have a requirement to read some fields of json data from a file to compose a new json list. The file is generated by `reading data from multiple servers via pssh`

```bash
# pssh_result.txt
[1] 14:44:51 [SUCCESS] 1.1.1.1
{"field1":"value11","field2":"value12","field3":"value13",...}
[2] 14:44:51 [SUCCESS] 1.1.1.2
{"field1":"value21","field2":"value22","field3":"value23",...}
...
...
```

I can only extract fields from it at the moment, but I don't know how to combine them into a finished json array

```bash
#!/bin/sh
input="pssh_result.txt"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    # echo "$line"
    if jq -e . >/dev/null 2>&1 <<<"$line"; then
        read field1 field3 <<<$(echo $(echo $line |
            jq -r '.field1, .field3'))
        example_item=$(jq --null-input \
            --arg field1 "$field1" \
            --arg field3 "$field3" \
            '{"alias1": $field1, "alias2": $field3}')

        echo $example_item
    fi
done <"$input"
```

the output are as follow

```bash
sh test.sh 
{ "alias1": "value11", "alias2": "value13" }
{ "alias1": "value21", "alias2": "value23" }
```

But I want to **merge** it into a large json array for later sending to a third party for processing, and the **desired result** is as follows

```bash
[
    {
        "alias1": "value11",
        "alias2": "value13"
    },
    {
        "alias1": "value21",
        "alias2": "value23"
    }
]
```

I also thought about putting it into a array and then passing it through something like `join(arr,",")`, but it didn't work as expected.

How do I get the results I want? I really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the input looks like

```
[1] 14:44:51 [SUCCESS] 1.1.1.1
{"field1":"value11","field2":"value12","field3":"value13"}
[2] 14:44:51 [SUCCESS] 1.1.1.2
{"field1":"value21","field2":"value22","field3":"value23"}
```

(Note that I have fixed the broken JSON on the lines that have JSON objects.)

... then you can extract the lines that you want with `grep`:

```bash
grep '^{' file
```

or

```bash
grep -v -F '[SUCCESS]' file
```

or similar `grep` command.

You may then parse the stream of JSON objects using `jq -s`, which will automatically read them into an array.  This allows you do the processing of the data like so:

```bash
grep '^{' file | jq -s 'map({ alias1: .field1, alias2: .field3 })'
```

With the input shown above in `file`, this would generate

```json
[
  {
    "alias1": "value11",
    "alias2": "value13"
  },
  {
    "alias1": "value21",
    "alias2": "value23"
  }
]
```

---

If you are uninterested in changing your already existing initial parsing of the input and want to put your output into an array, then it's just a matter of passing it through `jq -s .`:

```bash
$ cat file
{ "alias1": "value11", "alias2": "value13" }
{ "alias1": "value21", "alias2": "value23" }
```

```bash
$ jq -s . file
[
  {
    "alias1": "value11",
    "alias2": "value13"
  },
  {
    "alias1": "value21",
    "alias2": "value23"
  }
]
```

---

A hack to read *directly* from the original file with `jq` is to read the data as raw strings, try to convert them into valid JSON, and then throw away any errors:

```bash
$ cat file
[1] 14:44:51 [SUCCESS] 1.1.1.1
{"field1":"value11","field2":"value12","field3":"value13"}
[2] 14:44:51 [SUCCESS] 1.1.1.2
{"field1":"value21","field2":"value22","field3":"value23"}
```

```bash
$ jq -R 'fromjson | { alias1: .field1, alias2: .field3 }' file 2>/dev/null
{
  "alias1": "value11",
  "alias2": "value13"
}
{
  "alias1": "value21",
  "alias2": "value23"
}
```

This could then be gathered in an array:

```bash
$ jq -R 'fromjson | { alias1: .field1, alias2: .field3 }' file 2>/dev/null | jq -s .
[
  {
    "alias1": "value11",
    "alias2": "value13"
  },
  {
    "alias1": "value21",
    "alias2": "value23"
  }
]
```

Note that we need the two separate invocations of `jq` here as the first `jq` invocation would terminate prematurely if it tried to convert the input into JSON with `fromjson` into an array (or any other structure other than individual objects).